# Logging dml operation without trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I need to log all dml statements in order they performs on table but cannot use dml trigger. Have any ideas? Actually I shouldn't make that doing longer so I think I believe I can read log journal but don't know how to do it.

Comment: oracle has built in auditing: select * from sys.aud$

Comment: Does "all DML statements" include `select` statements?  Or just `insert`, `update`, and `delete` statements?  Do you need to know the values that were manipulated?  Or merely that the statement `update table_name set col1 = :1 where key = :2` was executed 13 times?

Comment: @JustinCave no i don't need select statements. I need both old and new values were manipulated

Comment: What are you going to do with the data?  Are you willing to try to parse SQL statements to get the old and new values out?  Or are you just visually inspecting the SQL rather than trying to do something like producing a historical report of the data changes?  Can you enable supplemental logging?  Are you really using 9i?  That's a pretty ancient release that has been depricated for many years.

Comment: @JustinCave realy 9i. Changes will be selected from another db with the same table to synchronize it.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using built-in replication technologies (probably limited to materialized views in 9i though you could possibly use Streams if you still happen to have a support contract to be able to get the appropriate patches for ancient software)?

Comment: @JustinCave cause probably replication will also be via web connection without any db links

Comment: I'm hard pressed to believe that you're going to create a solution that is much more efficient or much more supported than creating a trigger to store the state of the row on every modification.  You could create a materialized view log instead and read the materialized view log but functionally that's very similar to a trigger.  You could potentially use Streams or CDC but I'd have concerns about those technologies on a version of Oracle that old particularly if you don't have an active support contract.

Comment: You could use LogMiner to read from the redo logs, assuming the database is in archivelog mode and you can guarantee that the archive logs that the remote server needs will always be available.  You'd need to enable supplemental logging and write a fair amount of code to try to parse the SQL statements that you get from LogMiner to be able to apply them to the remote server-- whatever you gain from not having the trigger will almost certainly be lost in all that string parsing.